# Temporarily save modified buffers

Tags: auto-save, session

I would like to achieve the following workflow:

When I open files to edit and close emacs, I want this changed files to be temporarily saved, so that I can very quickly close Emacs / move to other work items. The next time I open Emacs, these "scratch-items" shall be recovered.

I am aware of auto-save, but I want Emacs to "silently" open the auto-save files instead of prompting me what to do for every buffer.

Comment: "Temporarily saved" seems like a contradiction in terms, unless you literally mean saving to the tmp filesystem (which seems unlikely, but I can't tell for sure). Please re-phrase this so it is clear what you are actually asking for.

Comment: Sounds like perhaps `recentf-mode` is what you want, but it's not clear from your question. (It does not save the unsaved state, however. It just gives you quick access to your last-used files.) See also the Emacs manual, node [Auto Save](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save.html).

Comment: @JohnDoe can you edit your question to be just one thing? It seems like one of your questions was answered, but I'm not 100% sure what the remaining part you need is.